# Пользовательское событие

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть свое событие, описанной в основной части кода. Описываю класс, в котором хочу вызвать данное событие. Как это сделать? Хотелось бы еще и с параметром вызов делать.

Comment: Почему удален код? Какое отношение к вопросу имеют регулярные выражения? Поставил на голосование по удалению.

Comment: Можно де самостоятельно удалить.

Answer (score 3):

Добавьте класс:

```
public class TextEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Message { get; private set; }

    public TextEventArgs(string message)
    {
        Message = message;
    }
}
```

сгенерировать событие в коде ваше класса MyEvent:

```
MyEvent?.Invoke(this, new TextEventArgs("i.ua", MyEvent));
```

В основном коде подписаться на получение уведомлений:

```
MyConnet.Info += TextLogAdd;
```

Сам метод TextLogAdd может выглядеть так:

```
public void TextLogAdd(object sender, TextEventArgs e)
    {
        textBoxLog.AppendLine(e.Message);
    }
```